# Call a PHP function within a class

Tags: php, function

I know I might be missing something very obvious, but I am trying to factorize some code by defining a function, and for some reason it doesn't work.
I have a class called Gateway, and within this class two functions fixedVariables() and call(). Within these both functions, I need to calculate an array and an encoded signature (an extract of my code is shown below). As long as I have this signature calculated as shown below, everything works perfect:

```
class Gateway {
       //There is more than that, I am not showing everything here
        public function fixedVariables() {
            //This function contains a lot of stuff, in particular an array called $hidden
            //#Clean calculation of the string to be encoded
            ksort($hidden);
            $concatenated_string = '';
            foreach ($hidden as $key => $val) {
                if (substr($key, 0, 5) == "vads_"){
                    $concatenated_string = $concatenated_string . $val . "+";
                }
            }
            $concatenated_string = $concatenated_string . $certificate;
    
            #Proper encoding to get the signature
            if ($algo == 'HMACSHA256')
                $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $concatenated_string, $certificate, true));
            if ($algo == 'SHA1')
                $signature = sha1($concatenated_string);
            if ($algo == 'NONE')
                $signature = $concatenated_string;
            $hidden['signature'] = $signature;
        
        return $hidden;
        }
    }
```

Now of course, I want to factorize the calculation of the signature (as it is called in two different places). And that's where I may be missing something. I replace the above by pretty much the following:

```
class Gateway {
        public function getSignature($hidden, $algo, $certificate){
        //#Clean calculation of the string to be encoded
            ksort($hidden);
            $concatenated_string = '';
            foreach ($hidden as $key => $val) {
                if (substr($key, 0, 5) == "vads_"){
                    $concatenated_string = $concatenated_string . $val . "+";
                }
            }
            $concatenated_string = $concatenated_string . $certificate;
    
            #Proper encoding to get the signature
            if ($algo == 'HMACSHA256')
                $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $concatenated_string, $certificate, true));
            if ($algo == 'SHA1')
                $signature = sha1($concatenated_string);
            if ($algo == 'NONE')
                $signature = $concatenated_string;

            return $signature;
        }

       //There is more than that, I am not showing everything here
        public function fixedVariables() {
            //This function contains a lot of stuff, in particular an array called $hidden
            $hidden['signature'] = getSignature($hidden, $algo, $certificate);
        
        return $hidden;
        }
    }
```

But for some reason my code doesn't compile. I checked on a PHP online sandbox, there doesn't seem to be any syntax error in my code. But when loaded of my website, the page freezes (as it there was such a syntax error). I don't get it. I tried the following, none of the below worked:

- Defining the getSignature function as public static or as private
- Changing the names of the arguments

I'm sure it's something very obvious which I am missing, but I would really appreciate to understand what exactly! Best regards,

Guillaume

Comment: because you did not provide the full code.as current I can see one error.in `fixedVariables ` function.you called `getSignature ` function.but it should be called like this `$this-> getSignature()`.If you have further question,you can find the error log somewhere else

Comment: Can you show the code where you are trying to access the class methods?